# C# help swap values

Tags: c#

I have a simple project, in which a button is assigned with a character and I want it to swap values with 2 button clicks only.

[image]

For example, when I first click "G" it will hold and when I click a second button for example "N", G and N will swap values.

I've managed to start it but don't know what to do next in order for me to swap with 2 clicks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Guess_Jumble_Word
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      int count = 0;
      string tmp, txt1, txt2;

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      { 
          //G ug A
          count++;

          if (count == 1)
          {
              btn1.Text = btn1.Text.ToString();
          }
          else if(count == 2)
          {

          }
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

      }

      private void resetCount()
      {
          count = 0;
      }

    /* private void buttonG() { } */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the same click event and count how many times you clicked it and keep track of the first button clicked and switch at the second click

```
Button firstButton;
int count = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        firstButton = button;
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 1)
    {
        count = 0;
        string temp = button.Text;

        button.Text = firstButton.Text;
        firstButton.Text = temp;

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've never thought of it that way. So simple and precise. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
int count = 0;
Button first = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonClick(sender);
}

private void buttonClick(object sender)
{
  count++;
  if (count == 1)
  {
    first = sender as Button;
  }
  else if(count == 2)
  {
    swap(sender);
    resetCount();
  }
}

private void swap(object sender)
{
  if(first != null) //just in case, but it should not happen
  {
    Button second = sender as Button;
    string aux = second.Text;
    second.Text = first.Text;
    first.Text = aux;
  }
}

private void resetCount()
{
    count = 0;
}
```

As you can see I'm saving a reference to the first click button, since otherwise I won't we able to do the swap on the second click.

Since you want the same behaviour in all your buttons by doing it like this you only need to call `buttonClick` in each one of the `_Click` methods.

Comment: At first, I was quite confused but later  on, I've studied your code and traced the methods and understood your logic. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked, the swap itself is the same as the one presented by CNuts. You should mark his answer as the correct one if it help you work out a solution to your problem.